# Django - Mac development, environment hell

Tags: python, django, macos, python-imaging-library

I was trying to setup Django dev environment on Mac and arrived into a hell. It all started when trying to install **PIL**, which failed after trying 15 or so different recipes I found on blogs. So I wanted to install the Python, this time 2.7, and reinstall setuptools, easy_install, pip from scratch.

After just installing Python 2.7, and easy_install with setuptools for 2.7, this all in turn created such a mess that is unbelievable. Different version of Python are installed everywhere, easy_install is installed everywhere and points randomly to different python hashbangs (sometimes to #!/usr/bin, #!/usr/local/, #!/Library/...)

Now I can't even do easy_install pip, which I always could. So I'm already in a hell and I haven't even attempted to install MySQL yet.

My question finally is did anyone bump into such problems, it would help enough to know that I'm not alone.

Second, would it be easier to set up the entire environment on Ubuntu than it is on a Mac?

Thirdly, is there any guide that can really clearly explain how to set up but also tear down the stack for Python development on a Mac?

Comment: Messing with system libraries can be messy. I recommend looking into Homebrew or Macports so you don't need to install these things from scratch.

Comment: I did install Python 2.7 with brew in which case I managed to install easy_install and pip but it failed to install PIL. Then I brew uninstall Python 2.7, used DMG and from then it failed at pip installation. It really looks like you need a larger team to be able to afford the bandwidth of maintaining Python environment on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone through the same hell 2 weeks ago :)

I needed to make working python 2.7 and virtualenv on OSX 10.6.8.
You haven't mentioned virtualenv in your question but I strongly recommend it. That way you minimize amount of globally installed packages. Everything is... cleaner.
My idea is to only have following things globally:

- python (from brew)
- pip (via easy_install)
- virtualenv (via pip)
- virtualenvwrapper (via pip)
- other through either virtualenv or buildout

I've just checked and pip PIL installs fine within my virtualenv.

Here are notes from this battle ([gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/1034876)):

```
#NOTE: .pydistutils.cfg seems to be not compatible with brew install python
#areas I needed to clean before installation
#clean up ~/Library/Python
#clean up .local
brew install python
easy_install pip
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper
mkdir $HOME/.virtualenvs
```

Example .bash_profile:

```
#homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${PATH}

# homebrew python 2.7
export PATH="/usr/local/share/python:${PATH}"

#virtualenv wrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't hurt to run a VM with `vagrant`. This post should tell you more:
http://stevelosh.com/blog/2011/06/django-advice/

Of course using virtualenv should also help alleviate some of these issues.

Comment: I couldn't even reach a point of having Python 2.7 with easy_install, so that I could install PIP so that I could install virtualenv. I installed Python2.7 from DMG, installed setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg, and then tried installing PIP with easy_install, but got this: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getstate__'. Then I checked around the file system to find a complete mess.

Comment: I would still recommend using a VM unless you plan on deploying to an OS X server. You should be developing in an environment that is closest to your production instance.

Comment: I could also install Ubuntu on VMWare if Mac is really unsuitable for Django dev. That or we drop Django and use something else.

Comment: You would have similar problems if you installed multiple versions of python on any operating system. If you are considering dropping a whole technology stack simply because it is harder to set up a development environment, then I don't know what to say. The article I posted should explain everything you need to set up a good Django dev environment.

Comment: Maybe technology stack is ok if you have a big company with 5 people employed to install PIL only. Every possible technology on every possible platform (even embedded devices) weren't as challenging to install a simple library.

Comment: Very few big companies with technology teams that are as large as you describe are using Django/Python. I am the only Django developer at my startup and I found the steps listed in the article quite easy to follow for even a small project.  What will you do when you need to move your application to production? If it is dependent on your OS X environment, you will have lots of trouble. There are tools meant to help you not just now, but throughout the development/deployment process.

Comment: I recommend Vagrant for your VM needs. It'd a wrapper around VirtualBox and a breeze to learn and use.

Comment: Very nice. I was going to suggest VirtualBox, since that's what I use, but then I found myself educated about Vagrant. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

> Second, would it be easier to set up
>   the entire environment on Ubuntu than
>   it is on a Mac?

To answer this question (though I never used Mac though): I never had problems setting up a python environment for Django development on Ubuntu. Though in any case you should go with the built-in Python version if possible. Attempting to install any other Python versions usually ends up messy. Luckily with Ubuntu 11.04 the standard version is already 2.7.

Comment: What about the infamous PIL? Did you have any problems installing and using it?

Comment: Nope, not in Ubuntu. `pip install PIL` or `apt-get python-imaging` both worked for me. Though also better to decide which one you want to install. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using django development environment on a MAC OS X 10.8 with python 2.7. I don't use virtualenv ore some other things.

With all the respect can say that there is NO ANY PROBLEMS to develop on a mac. Mac is a UNIX like system and you've probably seen that all tools for developers have MAC ports.

As for the setup mess. It's a good idea to use virtualenv. As for PIL installation. I needed to compile it with TrueType. As I'm in common with UNIX like environments it was not heavy task for me to compile PIL from sources using GCC (it's already installed on a MAC)... There are some mess with Django to setup virtualenv... There are certainly lots of articles to setup it on Google.

I use Eclipse and write all my PYTHONPATH variables there. You can forget installing everything  like in Linux and try not to make anymore mess with installed tools. Try to [read THIS](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2011/06/django-better-way-to-install-eclipse.html) article if you  feel like you're ok to use Eclipse for your development on a MAC. It also has a recipe to avoid mess with installation of many copies of Python and other dev utils.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have had problems with MacOS. I think rather than trying to figure it out I just switched to Ubuntu. I use a mac with Ubuntu installed in VMware Fusion. I have developed on both and prefer the Ubuntu because I'm just more comfortable with installing packages and the file structure.

I love using the VM because I'm never scared of having to start over. I can get a whole new OS installed and get the packages with what I use in just a few hours. Not to mention with 6month rollouts I can do complete installs of new versions instead of updates.

Depending on your production environment, it may be beneficial to use an OS that is similar, if you can install a package on ubuntu desktop, you already know how to do it on ubuntu server.